# How can I get the latest row(s) from a table based on 2 columns and don't conflict with eachother?

Tags: mysql

This is basically a private message system for another system I am creating.
I have a table that is set up with id, transmitter, receiver, message. The transmitter and receiver are numbers.

The current system is setup so that each user has their own number that is unique. When they message another user it inserts it into the table. With that, the transmitter and receiver will have both values of the user.

I want to show the user each number they have messaged and showing the last message from their conversation(Everything else is good like showing all messages from a single conversation) whether it be from that user or the other user.

I know that might have not explained it very well so I will try to use an example

transmitter, receiver, message

```
456, 123, Hi!
456, 789, I have a question
456, 789, Can you help?
789, 456, Yes
```

So in the example, we have 123, 456, 789. We will be 456 for this. On our side we should see 123, 789. The most recent message for 123 should be Hi! and the most recent for 789 should be Yes. If we were to respond to 789 our message would be that most recent one or if 123 responded back then that would be the most recent for the 123 conversation.

I hope I was able to explain everything and hoped the example helped.

Comment: Can you share your entire table schema?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Here you go ```CREATE TABLE `phone_messages` (
 `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `transmitter` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
 `receiver` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
 `message` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
 `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
 `isRead` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `owner` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=235
;```

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

A `UNION` sounds like something you will find useful:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM `phone_messages`
        WHERE `transmitter` = ###
        ORDER BY `time` DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS `last_sent`

    UNION

    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM `phone_messages`
        WHERE `receiver` = ###
        ORDER BY `time` DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS `last_received`
) AS `last_message`
ORDER BY `time` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The first segment will get you the last message sent by the person ID in question.

The second segment will get you the last message received by the person ID in question.

The outer select gives you the most recent of those two.

Comment: Getting an error when trying to use this. SQL syntax error; near UNION SELECT * from `phone_messages` where `receiver` = '' at line 8. I've run it through an SQL checker and it came back fine though.

Comment: After some additional testing, where I found I got same sort of syntax issues as you, I was able to get a working query.

Comment: I appreciate the help. Unfortunately, the query is not what I am waning but it is close.I need it to select the last messages from all different users based on one. So You have uses 123, 456 ,789 I need to select messages from 456 and get the last one from 123, 789 but the last one can be from either 123 or 456(789,456). So in this case there should be 2 results instead of one.

Comment: So you want all the last messages sent by 123 to each unique user, and all the last messages received by 123, sent by unique users? If so, please update your question, with both the table schema as you were asked in the post comments, and a more precise explanation of what you're looking for. It will be be easier for someone to assist you.

Comment: The explaination is precise you just aren't understating it properly. There is only one table so I'm not sure where the second one came from. I want it like how it would be in the messages app on your phone. You have a list of users you have messaged or gotten a message from and it shows the last message sent by either you or the other person. So if you and user 123 are messaging eachother you should see the last message sent from the conversation. As well if you are messaging user 789 then you should see the last message from them as well. I'm not sure how else to word it

Comment: Here is some example data from the table https://i.imgur.com/LfgAPUr.png. If we are user 654321987 then we should see 456789123 and the last message sent should be "BLAH" as well as seeing 456123789 with the message "IDK"